# How to get color name from UIColor constants

Tags: ios, uicolor

I want to show some color name in PickerView, which are constant from UIColr class

```
pickerContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor orangeColor],[UIColor purpleColor],[UIColor yellowColor], nil ];
```

and my implemented function for PickerView label is

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  return [(UIColor *)[self.pickerContent objectAtIndex:row] description];
}
```

i Know **description** will not give me my desired output.

so please help with your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to Show only colour names in Picker view Then Just take another `NSArray`

`NSArray *colourArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"redColor",@"orangeColor",@"purpleColor",@" yellowColor", nil ];`

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{ return [colourArray objectAtIndex:row]; 

}
```

Comment: sorry but in what way your answer is different then mine?

Comment: Before you answered i commented the same thing And Then i moved it to Answer. But the problem is in the Same time Answer got posted.